# Arrays.asList(int_array).indexOf(int_element) returns -1 even if element is present java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have taken an int[] as input. For searching the index of an integer in the array I used `Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(element)` method. However, I am getting index as `-1` even if the element is present in the array.

Comment: Post the code and sample data for which you get this output.

Answer (score 2):

int[] is one object, so Arrays.asList(arr) puts one object in the list, you need to put values from int[] one by one

Comment: Or use `Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList())`.